# Cannot change ownership of a subdirectory under a mount directory

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I am unable to change the ownership of a directory, under a mounted drive.
Already tried `sudo chown mysql:mysql /personal/mysql` and `sudo chmod --reference=/var/lib/mysql /personal/mysql`.

However, the mysql directory i.e., /personal/mysql is owned by root.

```
ls -la /personal/mysql | grep mysql

drwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4096 Oct 29 06:32 mysql
```

Comment: Could you provide the output of running sudo chown -v mysql:mysql /personal/mysql
The output of the -v (verbose) could provide some insight as to why the directory isn't changing ownership.

Comment: @Dylan this is what I see when I execute the command `changed ownership of '/personal/mysql' from root:root to mysql:mysql` but the ownership still remains the same, and does not get assigned to mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the uid and gid as options when you create the initial mount using the mount command. The uid and gid can be found by running the id command:

So for example, if:

```
id mysql
```

returns:

```
uid=10171(mysql) gid=10171(mysql)
```

Run mount with:

```
mount -type ... //...... /path/to/dir -o uid=10171,gid=10171,....
```